# get the number of shares done using my app alone

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a webpage where i can have customers share about multiple urls using below href

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=12345&link=www.petsytest.com&...&...

So based on the user action, link changes, but the appid is always my facebook apps appid.

How can I find the number of shares happened through  my app id.? Is it possible anywhere in

developer.facebook.com. If not , is there any other way?

Comment: If not via your `app_id`, here is a way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9464265/get-the-number-of-facebook-shares-of-a-specific-url (be reminded that FQL is going to be deprecated)