# Link facebook share count with file_get_contents

Tags: php, facebook, count, share, file-get-contents

I'm tring do get the total number of sharing a link on facebook with the function "file_get_contents".

This is my code:

```
$url = x;
$data = file_get_contents('http://graph.facebook.com/?id=".$url');
$obj = json_decode($data, true);
$like_no = intval($obj->{'shares'});
echo $like_no;
```

I tried this and it doesn't work. But file_get_contents is enabled on my server so i don't find the solution... If you can help me! Thanks in advance :)

Comment: $data is what i get from the facebook graph.
For exemple: http://graph.facebook.com/?id=http://facebook.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks with your help i find the solution and without the api (i'm happy :))

For people intereset in:

```
$url = x;
$data = file_get_contents('http://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?method=links.getStats&format=json&urls='.$url);
$obj = json_decode($data, true);
$like_no = $obj[0]['total_count'];
```

Comment: Yeap ! Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: no probleme you was very reactif on my demand and it's worth all mistake! :)

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You need an access token to access that link, which can be obtained by registering as a developer and creating an application.</strike>

Some links that might be helpful :

1) Facebook developers : https://developers.facebook.com/

2) PHP SDK : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/4.0.0

3) Graph API documentation : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api

You need to connect to facebook graph api using an OAuth2 client and it requires you to read their documentation.

L.E. It seems that I am wrong. You don't actually need an access token to get those informations.

Check this answer : [Get the number of facebook *shares* of a specific URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9464265/get-the-number-of-facebook-shares-of-a-specific-url)

Comment: Thanks i was thinking i don't need it. Have you a little hack for fast authentification (i have app and secret key). I would like to not use facebook php sdk because i think it gonna slow my website.

Comment: First of all, the SDK won't slow your website. Secondly, the easiest way is to use their PHP SDK, otherwise you will have to manually code the OAuth2 client library.

Comment: So if i have to use their SDK, i need to integrate there files to my website. They say that "The Facebook SDK for PHP v4 requires PHP 5.4 or greater.". I have a wordpress website which use previous version of PHP. How can i do?

Comment: Have you tried https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/3.2.3 PHP SDK v3.2.3 ?

Comment: I'm tring with it but they don't speak about how get link information like number of share.

I've got this for the connection:

`require 'facebook-php-sdk/src/facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'xxx',
  'secret' => 'xxx',
));
`
I don't know what to do next...