# How to get function callback in send button facebook?

Tags: javascript, facebook

Now i meet problem. I am using send button on my web page : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/send-button. But how i can set function callback (it help me count number send of my article and save database) when they are send successfully (they press send button on send dialog). Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the number of facebook \*shares\* of a specific URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9464265/get-the-number-of-facebook-shares-of-a-specific-url)

Comment: I am editing to describe another problem which your url not supported

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/faqs#events